# Can I add legends to a SmoothHistogram?

Tags: legending

Under the options menu for `Histogram`, there is an option called `ChartLegends`, which adds little boxes beside the plot to indicate which curve represents what. I cannot find a similar option for `SmoothHistogram`. I know that `PlotLegends` is new in version 9, and I would've expected the option to be valid for `SmoothHistogram` as well. Does anybody know of a way around this issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Even though the documentation for `SmoothHistogram` doesn't explicitly mention `PlotLegends` as an option, it is a valid option and works as expected:

```
SmoothHistogram[
 Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[c, 1], 500], {c, 0, 3}], 
 PlotLegends -> {"0", "1", "2", "3"}]
```

[image]

In general, it's a good idea to try out options that you *think* should work (for functions where it makes sense), but is missing in the documentation. More often, it's the case that the documentation is either lacking or the option was left out to make room for other more important ones.

You should also check if these options were defined for the function and disabled by default, which happens to be the case with `SmoothHistogram`:

```
Options[SmoothHistogram, PlotLegends]
(* PlotLegends -> None *)
```

Comment: What does disabled by default mean?

Comment: @soandos By "disabled" he means the option set to a value that doesn't do anything, e.g. `None`.